# Django use multiple databases dynamically without defining in settings

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-models

TL;DR: Besides my default django database, i need data pulled in from two different user-selected databases. not sure how to setup django to access these besides just running manual queries using connection.cursor().execute("SQL")

**Situtaion:** 
A process creates a sqlitedb. The database is imported into mysql. I'm writing a django app that interacts with that mysql database (call it StreamDB), another mysql database with additional info user needs to see (call this SourceDB), and of course the default Django app mysql DB (call it AppDB).

There will be two versions of SourceDB (prod and test) the StreamDB imported maps to data to one and only one of these SourceDB's.

I have a table/model in my "AppDB" that identifies these sources (the StreamDB name, which of the two SourceDB's it maps to, and some other data. Here's a sample record:

```
name: foo
path: /var/www/data/test/foo.sqlite
db_name: foo
source_db_name: bar
date_imported: 2014-05-03 10:20:30
```

These are managed through the django admin and added manually (or dyanmically via external script)

**Dilemma**
Depending on which source is selected, my SQL needs to join the tables from those two DB's. Example query with dyanmic db names in :

```
SELECT a.image_id, a.image_name, b.title, b.begin_time 
FROM <selected_streamdb>.image a JOIN <selected_sourcedb>.event b ON b.event_id = a.event_id
WHERE a.image_type = 'png'
```

Do I fill in  and  with variables perhaps?

**Question**
Is there anyway to use Django's ORM model in a situation like this? Can django grab the DATABASE.settings from a DB table? Do I create a model that manages this? (i.e. the source-table above?)

I don't mind managing db permissions on the backend (assume app database user in django settings has access to all of the databases)

Hope all of the above makes sense.